# Create linked list of multiple objects

Tags: c++, list

I need help, if I have:

```
class gameObject{
    public: //get and set;
    private: int x;
    int y;
    string texture;
}

class gun:public gameObject{
    public: //get and set;
    private: int ammo;
}

class armor:public gameObject ... ,
class boots:public gameObject...
```

How I can create a linked list of multiple derived objects from base class gameObject ? For example user have a menu: [1. Add object 2.Delete object]. If user choose 1 another menu appear [Type: 1-Gun 2-Armor]. After 4 objects added the list will be: 1.Gun 2.Armor 3.Gun 4.Boots.
I need an example to understand the concept.

Thanks.

Comment: `std::list<gameObject*>`

Comment: `std::list<std::unique_ptr<GameObject>>`

Answer (score 1):

> How I can create a linked list of multiple derived objects from base class gameObject ?

You would use `std::forward_list` (singly linked list) or `std::list` (doubly linked list) in conjunction with a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` (depending on owning semantic), as demonstrated below:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<gameObject>> list;
```

and then you would allocate objects using:

```
list.emplace_back(std::make_unique<gameObject>(...));
```

Answer (score 1):

Other peoples answers were good, but in case they were answering the wrong question here:

A pointer to the base type (smart or otherwise) can point to any of the derived types too, so you need to make a list of pointers to the base type.

You can't make a list of the base type itself, because the derived types are probably bigger and wouldn't fit. The language won't even let you try.

```
std::list<GameObject *> is ok.
std::list<GameObject> is not.
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use auto pointers for this.

```
list<unique_ptr<gameObject>> foo;

foo.push_back(make_unique<gun>());
foo.push_back(make_unique<armor>());

for(auto& i : foo){
    if(dynamic_cast<gun*>(i.get())){
        cout << "gun" << endl;
    }else if(dynamic_cast<armor*>(i.get())){
        cout << "armor" << endl;
    }
}
```

This example adds a `gun` and then an `armor` to `foo` as `unique_ptr<gameObject>`s.

In the `for`-loop we use a `dynamic_cast` to discern the type. The code will output:

> gun
>   armor

You can see an example of this code here: http://ideone.com/trj9bn